# Coldfusion CreateObject() Returns Instance of Wrong Object

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, createobject, coldfusion-2021

I'm running into an issue that only seems to affect our production server and without any apparent rhyme or reason.  Essentially, we're getting the following error (I'm going to use dummy names to illustrate the point):

> Message: Neither the method someFunction was found in component Components.services.SomeComponent nor was there any default method with this name present in any of the implementing interface.

This happens at a few different lines in the codebase but once it's been thrown, it will never get past that point again *until* clearing the Component Cache in CFADMIN.  Here's the kicker: the offending line in the code looks like this:

`<cfset var a = createObject("Components.services.app.ComponentA").someFunction() >`

It seems like the `createObject` call to create **ComponentA** is instead returning an instance of **SomeComponent**.  I've tried the following:

- The CreateObject calls in this section *had* been using dynamically created strings for the component path... I thought maybe something was getting polluted so now `Components.services.app.ComponentA`, `Components.services.app.ComponentB`, etc... are all hard-coded
- I tried using the `new` syntax instead of `createObject`
- I thought maybe there was something wrong with the path to where the Component Cache was getting confused, so I created a mapping to `./Components/services/app` called (for instance) "app" so that I could create the objects like `new app.ComponentA()` instead of `new Components.services.app.ComponentA`

Nothing seems to help -- none of this is reproducible in our UAT or anyone's dev environments and it's intermittent in production, but, again, once it's been thrown that server is done.  Clearing Component Cache in CFADMIN temporarily fixes it until someone will randomly throw it again hours later.

Some additional caveats:

- As we've moved and shuffled things around trying to find the cause of this problem, the specific line numbers and components seem to change but the behavior is always the same - `new ComponentC()` is instead creating `someComponent`... `new ComponentA()` is instead creating `someOtherComponent`
- This is only happening in one specific section of our codebase that uses a lot of object inheritance compared to the rest of our code.  We've combed through to make sure there aren't any circular references or anything like that, and the evil components (`someComponent`, `someOtherComponent`) are CFC's that live outside this directory
- The fact that clearing the Component Cache seems to resolve this really makes me suspicious of the Component Cache... I just don't know enough under the hood with CF to have any inkling *why* the cache may return an instance of a different object than the one it's calling

Next steps (none of these are ideal):

- Disabling the component cache altogether, don't want to take the performance hit
- Adding some ridiculous code to clear the component cache programmatically if an invalid method name error is thrown

Is there some way to granularly exclude certain CFC's from being retrieved from the Component Cache and force them to be re-evaluated when calling createObject()?

Comment: Do you have an `init()` function?
Does the behavior change if you call `init()` first?

Are you using clustering?
Do you have a component of the same name in a different path?
Can you just give THIS component a different (random) name and retest?

Comment: I'm curious about your init() method as well, but specifically are you returning anything other than "this" from your init method?  Whatever you return from the init method is what you get when creating an instance of that CFC.  If the component cache is affecting this, you can't have 2 CFCs of the same name in different applications when the cache is enabled as the com.foo.Bar path is locked into a path on disk.

Comment: "I'm going to use dummy names to illustrate the point". The _actual_ names might be relevant to this. Are any of the segments of the path particularly "generic" and might already be something CF is using under the hood for any reason? EG: "component", "class", "lib" etc. Also: have you checked for any other server-set or application-set CF mappings that might be interfering?

Comment: @AdamCameron that's the crazy part -- the components that are getting swapped in are so drastically differently named.  For instance, `CreateObject('Components.apiv2.banks')` is returning an instance of `Components.services.i18n.i18n`, and `CreateObject('Components.services.EAppFormV2.PDF10032.sectionCompanyInformation')` is returning an instance of `Components.services.MerchantApplicationLanguage`.  Both of these "wrong" CFC's are instantiated earlier in the method chain.

Comment: YIKES! [more chars to placate S/O]

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this behavior before when the component is using a path that has an Application mapping. I've seen this happen in a few different scenarios, but the most common scenario was like this:

In your Application.cfc, there's a mapping to your components that uses a relative path. Something like:

```
this.mappings["/Components"] = expandPath("../some/relative/path/com");
```

As long as the application is always initialized from the same folder as the `Application.cfc` then this works fine. However, if the application is initialized from a subfolder, then the `Components` mapping no longer points to the expected folder.

If you need to use a relative path for a mapping, you can avoid this by doing something like:

```
variables.rootFolder = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath());
this.mappings["/Components"] = variables.rootFolder & "../some/relative/path/com";
```

That should force the mapping to always use the same physical path folder, even when called from a subfolder.

Another scenario in which I've seen this happen is in a shared environment where there are multiple Applications with the same name.

If you have multiple instances of a website running that are using the same Application name in your `Application.cfc`, then the first website that is initialized ends up sharing it's mappings with the other application. If the applications are different, this can lead to components not being found.

Hopefully one of these two scenarios gets you on the right track to resolving your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the object,

`createObject("Components.services.app.ComponentA")`,

misses an attribute. The definition should be

`createObject("component", "Components.services.app.ComponentA")`.